# React clearing all keys rather than shallow merging single key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I am pulling in data from an API, and then allowing a user to modify that data within react, after which I will send the updated state to the server.

My API provides the following JSON:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Test Campaign",
    "impressions": 12,
}
```

And my component looks like so:

```
function Campaign() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  useEffect(async () => {
    const result = await axios('/campaigns/1')
    setData(result.data);
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setData({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
  }

  return (
    <div className='row'>
      <div className='col-12'>
        <h2>{ data.title }</h2>
        <input
          type='number'
          value={data.impressions}
          name='impressions'
          onChange={e => handleChange(e)}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

However, running this code causes all keys in the `data` state to be overwritten (and thus my `h2` tag displays nothing). It was my understanding that React State carried out a shallow merge, and so in this case would only update the `impressions` key:value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functional component's `useState` hook doesn't actually shallow merge state updates so you need to manage this yourself.

Use a [functional state update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) to access the previous state to shallow copy into the next state.

> **Note**
>
> Unlike the `setState` method found in class components, `useState`
> does not automatically merge update objects. You can replicate this
> behavior by combining the function updater form with object spread
> syntax:
>
> ```
> setState(prevState => {
>   // Object.assign would also work
>   return {...prevState, ...updatedValues};
> });
> ```

You may want to also ensure you maintain your state invariant. Since you are updating your state via key-value pairs I'm assuming you are *actually* using an object.

```
const [data, setData] = useState({}); // <-- empty object initial state

const handleChange = (event) => {
  setData(data => ({
    ...data, // <-- shallow copy existing state
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
  }));
}
```